# Event issues when rendering three js on a div

Tags: three.js

I built my scene in three js and everything was working properly when I rendered the scene on the . But now I need the scene to be on a div, 70% of the viewport to be specific, the other 30% being a left side panel with some info. I replaced every `window.height` and width for the width and height of the div itself, but now the events are all broken. I tried bubbling and capturing but the problem seems to be related with the camera or something in three js, because when I hover on a corner something is happening...but nothing is happening when i hover/click on the 3d globe. I google everything and didn't find an answer or people with similar issues..I'm hopeless, help? Thanks.

Edit: here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2L686cnw/

Comment: Please provide a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably as a [SO snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). We're going to need a lot more context about how the events are set up, and what they are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update all for the renderer relevant variables on window resize?
Just like this:

```
var onWindowResize = function(){
  renderWidth = element.offsetWidth;
  renderHeight = element.offsetHeight;
  camera.aspect = renderWidth/renderHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(renderWidth, renderHeight);
};

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  onWindowResize();
});
```

Comment: I did. Everywhere in my app where I had "document.width" or "document.height" i replace for the div's dimensions :| . The events are not triggering...

Comment: but did you either add an event listener to window like in the code above?

Comment: yes, i also have a onResize handler, the resize isn't the issue.

Comment: are you using the three.js Raycaster?

Comment: Yes. to get the intersections and do some logic when you click on the globe (markers expand).

Comment: when i zoom in a lot, some of the events trigger...could it had something to do with the camera?

Comment: hmm I'm not very familiar with the raycaster, maybe you have to update your raycaster on window resize too with this: raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

Comment: because it only has the scene code. not the html or anything. Well I don't know..I'm hopeless. Thanks though.

Comment: it would be helpful if you add the basic html and css snippets as also the raycaster part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166471/discussion-between-questionaccount-and-joao-vilaca).

Answer (score 1):

The issue sounds like that you get wrong viewport coordinates for your click position. Most three.js examples add event listeners to `window` or `document` object and using `event.clientX` (and clientY) to transform the mouse screen coordinates to viewport coordinates to use it for raycasting.

Having the 3D scene within a separate div covering only part of the page, it should be a bit different:

```js
function onClick(event) {
  var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    mouse.x = (event.offsetX / panelWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.offsetY / panelHeight) * 2 + 1;

  // do raycasting
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

Comment: that's exactly what i did, everywhere i saw `document` i replaced for my div, and everywhere i saw `window.width/height` i replace for the div dimensions...but the X and Y of the mouse were all screwed :|

Comment: Did you also use `event.offsetX` instead of `event.clientX`?